# How to control the picture that shows in Facebook when somebody likes your blog post?

Tags: image, facebook, blogs, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

well everything is in the question. I am talking about a blog or any website that is outside of Facebook: for example www.example.com/blogpost1

For now, Facebook chooses the picture from the RSS feed, which makes not much sense, well I can't find any reason why it would take this picture instead of another one. The code of this picture is this one: img src="xxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/xxx/images/logo_flux. jpg"

I'prefer it would take my logo.jpg representing the website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Open Graph Meta Tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

> If you use Open Graph tags, the
>   following six are required:
>
> ```
> og:title - The title of the entity.
> og:type - The type of entity. You must select a type from the list of Open Graph types.
> og:image - The URL to an image that represents the entity. Images must be at least 50 pixels by 50 pixels. Square images work best, but you are allowed to use images up to three times as wide as they are tall.
> og:url - The canonical, permanent URL of the page representing the entity. When you use Open Graph tags, the Like button posts a link to the og:url instead of the URL in the Like button code.
> og:site_name - A human-readable name for your site, e.g., "IMDb".
> fb:admins or fb:app_id - A comma-separated list of either the Facebook IDs of page administrators or a Facebook Platform application ID. At a minimum, include only your own Facebook ID.
> ```

Comment: great! thanks, looks like open graph is quite nice
Now I guess if I want to define a picture for every post of my blog, I need some php do make this tag dynamic, right? hmmm

Comment: well it was not working until i validated it with this tool : http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

Comment: BUT it seems I have to do it for every URL.... am I doing anything wrong? I know I let out some tags, but that doesnt look like its the problem... site is http://blog.viveoeurope.com

Comment: @gimmedonuts: You need to add ALL mandatory tags. Check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940030/facebook-like-button-open-graph-meta-tags-and-multiple-posts-in-wordpress/5940842#5940842)

Comment: well i don't beleive you need all of them because you can verify one URL and it works, even without all of them...but thanks for the link, that's perfect